# Facebook Plugin in for unity, key hash incorrect

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login

Unity 5.3.0 Facebook Plugin 7.3.0

I am trying to log on to Facebook in my Unity app.  I am doing a development build at this point and not a signed release build.  In the editor, Facebook settings shows one Key hash value.  When I build and run the app on the device, the login fails with the following message:

*[ 01-05 15:32:12.551  6001: 6001 V/com.facebook.unity.FB ]
Exception during service
com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 404 [message]: Key hash DIFFERENT_KEY_HASH= does not match any stored key hashes. 
sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"error":"Invalid key hash. The key hash DIFFERENT_KEY_HASH= does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/12345678909876","callback_id":"1","key_hash":"DIFFERENT_KEY_HASH=\n"})*

The key hash in the message is different from the one in the Unity editor.  I had both key hashes added to the facebook developer's console.  I still get the above error message.

Why are there two different key hash values, one displayed in the editor and one in the logcat?  Is this a problem? Which one is correct? Why would this error continue even after the Facebook developer console has been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat's one is correct. I normally use to do this. That is put the editor Key Hash in Facebook app, then check the log, add that key hash too. :)

Double check your key hash (log's one).

Paste your log in answer too, if possible.

But my answer is the log's key hash should work.

Comment: Thanks @Hamza, I had our client add the correct hashes (they control the facebook console) but of course they added them to the wrong app. I appreciate the help.